# How to keep node-dbox token between page refreshes in NodeJS/Express

Tags: node.js, express, dropbox

Im trying to put together a little application using `NodeJS`, `node-dbox` and `Express`.
When requesting for `DropBox` authorization - [it's a 3 step process](https://github.com/sintaxi/node-dbox#how-to-use), first need to get `request_token`, then user authorizes them visiting dropbox page, and only then request for `access_token`, based on `request_token` and the fact that user has authorized request.

However, by the time I served the page for step 1 and 2 (getting `request_token`, and providing user with url)  - `request_token` instance is gone!, so in step 3 I can't request for an `access_token`, because it requires `request_token` being passed

I'm trying to save `request_token` in a cookie, but given that contains sensitive data, sending it to the client may not be such a good idea. Any ideas?

Simplified code is below:

```
(function() {
    var dbox = require('dbox'),
        config = require('easy-config'),
        express = require('express'),
        dboxApp = dbox.app(config.dropbox_credentials),
        app = express();

    app.use(express.cookieParser());

    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        dboxApp.requesttoken(function(status, request_token) {
            res.cookie('request_token', JSON.stringify(request_token));
            res.send("<a href='" + request_token.authorize_url + "' targe='_new'>authorize via dropbox</a><br/>" + "<a href='/next'>next</a>");
        });
    });

    app.get('/next', function(req, res) {
        var request_token = JSON.parse(req.cookies.request_token);
        if(request_token) {
            dboxApp.accesstoken(request_token, function(status, access_token) {
                var client = dboxApp.client(access_token);
                client.account(function(status, reply){
                  res.send(reply);
                });
            });
        } else {
            res.send('sorry :(');
        }
    });

    app.listen(3000);

})();
```

bonus question: `client` is created with `access_token`, so either instance of client or `access_token` need to be maintained across page refreshes as well, whats the best approach?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? I'm struggling with the same thing - how to redirect back from dropbox to my app with the correct access token.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it working by doing the following:

According to the Dropbox Developer reference you can provide a callback url by specifying it along with the request as stated here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/20

```
https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=<request-token>&oauth_callback=<callback-url>
```

By storing the request token in the session and redirecting to the callback url you can then access the request token and be on your way. 
A couple of Express route handlers, passed a member id as a parameter, to request and then handle the response might look like this:

```
 linkAccount : function(req, res){
      var  memberId = req.params.memberId,
        appKey = 'MYAPPKEY',
        appSecret = 'MYAPPSECRET',
        dbox = require('dbox'),
        dboxApp = dbox.app({ "app_key": appKey, "app_secret": appSecret });


      req.session.dboxStore = {};
      req.session.dboxStore.dboxApp = dboxApp;

      dboxApp.requesttoken(function(status, request_token){
        req.session.dboxStore.request_token = request_token;
        console.log("request_token = ", request_token);

        res.redirect('https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize?oauth_token='+request_token.oauth_token+
          '&oauth_callback=http://myhost.local/linksuccess/dropbox/'+memberId);
        res.end;
      });
    },

    linkSuccess : function(req, res){
      var memberId = req.params.memberId;
      var appKey = 'MYAPPKEY';
      var appSecret = 'MYAPPSECRET';
      var dbox = require('dbox');
      var dboxApp = dbox.app({ "app_key": appKey, "app_secret": appSecret });
      var request_token = req.session.dboxStore.request_token;

      dboxApp.accesstoken(request_token, function(status, access_token){
        console.log('access_token = ', access_token);

        Member.setAuthToken(memberId, 'dropbox', access_token, function(err, member){
          res.render('index', { title:'SUCCESSFUL DROPBOX AUTH' });
          res.end;
        });
      });
    }
```